# Mean of non-diagonal elements of each row numpy

Tags: python, numpy, mean, numpy-ndarray, confusion-matrix

I essentially have a confusion matrix of size `n x n` with all my diagonal elements being `1`.

For every row, I wish to calculate its mean, excluding the `1`, i.e. excluding the diagonal value. Is there a simple way to do it in `numpy`?

This is my current solution:

```
mask = np.zeros(cs.shape, dtype=bool)
np.fill_diagonal(mask, 1)
print(np.ma.masked_array(cs, mask).mean(axis=1))
```

where `cs` is my `n x n` matrix

The code seems convoluted, and I certainly feel that there's a much more elegant solution.

Comment: Somehow I still prefer the original code to the concise one in the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A concise one using `summation` -

```
(cs.sum(1)-1)/(cs.shape[1]-1)
```

For a general case of ignoring diagonal elements, use `np.diag` in place of `1` offset -

```
(cs.sum(1)-np.diag(cs))/(cs.shape[1]-1)
```

Another with `mean` -

```
n = cs.shape[1]
(cs.mean(1)-1./n)*(n/(n-1))
```

Comment: Works perfectly!

Comment: Since confusion matrices are square matrices, there's no requirement to specifically take dimensionality of axis 1 when dividing the sum. But that's a good practice however.

Answer (score 2):

Another straightforward idea would be to use the built-in [**`numpy.average()`**](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.average.html) API where we supply `weights` for each of the elements in the confusion matrix to contribute to the average. This gives us the flexibility to exclude any of the elements in the matrix by setting their weights to zero. Below is a complete example:

```
# input array to work with
In [51]: arr 
Out[51]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  1,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10,  1, 12],
       [13, 14, 15,  1]])

# weightage for each of the elements in the input matrix
In [52]: weights = (arr != 1).astype(int)  # boolean mask would also work

# so, we give 0 weight to all the diagonal elements
In [53]: weights 
Out[53]: 
array([[0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0]])

# finally, use the weights when computing average over axis 1
In [54]: np.average(arr, axis=1, weights=weights) 
Out[54]: array([ 3.        ,  6.66666667, 10.33333333, 14.        ])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also replace the diagonal elements with np.nan and use np.nanmean() as follows:

```
# Make sure you use dtype float
cs = cs.astype('float64')

# Fill diagonal elements with np.nan
np.fill_diagonal(cs, np.nan)

np.nanmean(cs, axis=1)
```

Here you can also easily get the standard deviation with:

```
np.nanstd(cs, axis=1)
```